# Ember.js selecting value for model attribute from list

Tags: ember.js

I have a rather complicated set of models in my Ember application:

- A device has an OS, and an OS-version
- An OS has many OS-versions, one of which is the latest.

When I create a new device, I have a temporary model for not-yet-created-devices. This model collects all the data and copies into a device model. This is to ensure that all device models are internally consistent.

Inside the controller for the temporary model, I have to make a list of all the possible OSes a user can choose from. And once this is selected, I have to populate a list of OS-versions, which correspond to the chosen OS.

My template for the temp-model view looks like this:

> {{view Ember.Select
>
> ```
> prompt="Please select an OS"
> content=osClasses
> value=osClass
> class="form-control"
> id="select-os"
> optionLabelPath="content.name"
> ```
>
> }}

I've tried to set it up in my controller so that the array `osClasses` is populated doing something like this: `this.model["osClasses"] = this.store.find("osClass");`

However, there seems to be some sort of asynchronousity going on, because this select box is only populated some of the time, and the other times I get a crash which looks something like:

```
TypeError: end is null ember.js:42709
```

(I have suspected this MIGHT be related to a list of devices which is displayed elsewhere)

Is there some sort of awesome way to do this, which deals with any asynchronous problems?

Second, once I have actually selected the OS, I want to populate the array (and the select view) for the OS-versions. I tried something like this in my controller:
>

> model:{
>      name: "new device",
>      osClass: undefined,
>      osVersion: undefined,
>      osClasses: []
>     },
>
> onOsClassChanged: function() {
>
> ```
> console.log("NewDeviceController.onOsClassChanged()");
> if(this.model["osClass"])
>   this.model["osVersion"] = this.model["osClass"].latest;
> else
>   console.log("osClass is not")
> ```
>
> }.observes("osClass"),

In this example I'm not even trying to populate the second array, rather I just want to pick whichever is the latest OS-version for the given OS. This function triggers, as I would expect, but it always logs `osClass is not`, and doesn't really do what I want. Presumably this means that the Select view isn't manipulating the same model as me? What's more, I can't really access anything useful from inside this method.

Can anyone recommend a method for populating Select views like these? The way I'm doing it feels very weird, and it doesn't seem to be working anyway. Second: How are you supposed to manipulate models if you always have outdated references or no reference? I feel like I'm missing something big here.

Comment: When you set a value in an object in ember use the 'set'. Otherwise the data binding wont be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As blessenm commented and I discovered on my own: In order to trigger changes, I have to use 'set' on the Controller. (on the model doesn't seem to work). To get an updated version of the data, I have to use 'get'.